# POST: Exception Status expected:<201> but was:<200>

Tags: java, api, rest, spring-mvc, spring-test

Technically it should be a simple task, but I can't find the error.

I want to write a normal "POST method", but when I tested it, it came to a problem: `enter code here Status expected:<201> but what:<200>.`

My question is, why do I get an OK and not a CREATED?

**CODE:**

**PostMapping in Controller**

```
 @PostMapping
    public Optional<ADto> createA(@RequestBody ADto a){
        return Optional.ofNullable(a);
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
@Test
    void verifyPostA() throws Exception {
        var a = new ADto(1L, "a");

        var aText = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a);

        mockMvc.perform(
                        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/as")
                                .content(aText)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("1"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for a controller method that executes successfully and does not return `ResponseEntity` , the default response code is 200.

To configure the response code for such case , you can simply annotate `@ResponseStatus` on that controller method :

```java
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Optional<ADto> createA(@RequestBody ADto a){
        return Optional.ofNullable(a);
 }
```